# Is it possible to put two .git folders in one directory?

Tags: git, github

I use git mainly to backup my code, my idea is to backup my code twice in two different hostings, Github and Bitbucket for example. Thus, instead of copying code back and forth between the two repos, I put the `.git` of each on the same directory so when I `git add *` `git commit -m ""` and `git push` things happen simultaneously.
If not possible, is there any good solution?

Comment: You have an incorrect mental model of how Git and remote repositories work. You can add any number of remotes to the same local repository.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should ask a different question. But if I understood correctly: Yes, you can have multiple remotes you push to.

[pull/push from multiple remote locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849308/pull-push-from-multiple-remote-locations)

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes

If properly configured you would just push to both with 1 command:

```
git push
```

Or a simple example:

1. add additional remotes for this repo via `git remote add <YOUR_REMOTE_NAME> ssh://`
2. list remotes with `git remote -v`
3. push to both `git push origin && git push my-new-remote`

Perhaps you should read about git remotes a little.

- https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote
- https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/syncing